# django admin: adding a new object as a foriegn key child in admin interface

Tags: python, django

I have a custom user object `GameUser`, a profile `UserInfo` that attaches to each user with information, and a Weapon model that each profile gets associated to, but can only have one at a time.

I want to be able to look up and existing `GameUser` in my admin interface and, in the change form, have the option to create an associate a new Weapon to that `UserInfo` profile.

Here's my models:

```
class GameUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField()
    # ...etc

class UserInfo(models.Model):
    first = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # ...etc

    # relations
    user = models.OneToOneField(GameUser)
    weapon = models.ForeignKey('Weapon', null=True)

class Weapon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    # ...etc
```

And my `admin.py`:

```
class GameUserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = GameUser
        fields = ('email', 'password')

    def clean_password(self):
        return self.initial["password"]

class GameUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = GameUserChangeForm

    list_display = ('email', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

class UserInfoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Personal Information', {'fields': [
            'first', 'last']
        }),
        # ... etc
    ]

    list_display = ('first', 'last')
    search_fields = ['city', 'state'] 

admin.site.register(UserInfo, UserInfoAdmin)
admin.site.register(GameUser, GameUserAdmin)
```

If there is a Weapon associated with that `GameInfo`, I'd like to display it there inline. If not, I'd like to be able to create a new `Weapon` object for that `GameInfo` and set its fields.

I should mention I'm not married to `Weapon` being a `ForiegnKey` - it could certainly be a `OneToOneField` as well if that makes it easier.

What is the right way for me to do this in Django?

Comment: `tadaaam!`  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects is there what are you looking for?

Comment: Yes, that was my first thought. This would allow editing ("changing") a model connected via a foreign key, but it would not allow creating one, as far as I understand.

Comment: It allows changing and creating http://take.ms/NTl38 Product is a ForeignKey field